# How to show loading screen after click on url in webview using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, webview

I am trying to show loading screen when i click on webpage in webview using flutter. loading screen is showing after splash screen. But it's not showing after click on link of in webview.

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool isLoading;
  @override
  void initState() {
    isLoading = true;

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body:Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
      new WebView(
        initialUrl:"https://abcdef.com/",
        javascriptMode:JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onPageFinished: (_) {
          setState(() {
            isLoading = false;
          });
        },
      ),
      isLoading ? Center( child: CircularProgressIndicator()) : Container(),
      ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `onPageStarted` callback to your `Webview`, then set `isLoading` to `true`

Like this

```
Webview(
   initialUrl:"https://abcdef.com/",
   javascriptMode:JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
   onPageStarted: (_){
     setState(() => isLoading = true);
   },
   onPageFinished: (_) {
     setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
     });
   },
}
```